# how to pass value to VO which is inside map and VO

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

I have `CompanyProfileVO` in which I have declared `companyProfile_addressVOMap` as `map` of `String` and `VO`
i want to give value to the `company_name` which is present in side `AddressIdentificationVO` in the form of url encoded

How can I set value of `company_name` through url encoded form?

To get the value I'm using this

`CompanyProfileVO.getCompanyProfile_addressVOMap().get("COMPANY").getCompany_name()`

CompanyProfileVO.java

```
Map<String,AddressIdentificationVO> companyProfile_addressVOMap;
```

AddressIdentificationVO

```
@FormParam("company_name")
String company_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your Code you need to create two different Variable object 1 for json and 1 for XMl(URL encoded). you should pass your

```
Map<String,AddressIdentificationVO> companyProfile_addressVOMap;
```

`AddressIdentificationVO` inside `JSONVO` and call the JSON method When u hit the URL Encoded method .